# Getting error on Watson Speech To Text using WebSocket

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I'm receiving this error event from Watson Speech to Text when I try to pip the microphone input to it. Using NodeJS app based on this TJBot Code https://github.com/ibmtjbot/tjbot/tree/master/recipes/conversation

This is the error object that I get

```
=== Watson Speech to Text : An Error has occurred =====
_Event {
  type: 'error',
  isTrusted: false,
  _yaeti: true,
  target: 
   W3CWebSocket {
     _listeners: {},
     addEventListener: [Function: _addEventListener],
     removeEventListener: [Function: _removeEventListener],
     dispatchEvent: [Function: _dispatchEvent],
     _url: 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel',
     _readyState: 3,
     _protocol: undefined,
     _extensions: '',
     _bufferedAmount: 0,
     _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
     _connection: undefined,
     _client: 
      WebSocketClient {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        config: [Object],
        _req: null,
        protocols: [],
        origin: null,
        url: [Object],
        secure: true,
        base64nonce: 'XU/MDifsB9QqtrWn4vPFgw==' },
     onerror: [Function],
     onopen: [Function],
     onclose: [Function],
     onmessage: [Function] },
  cancelable: true,
  stopImmediatePropagation
```

: [Function] }
Press +C to exit.

This was working fine until some hours ago but suddenly stopped working. Any idea on what this error means ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my credentials were wrong. It seems that during migration to DIEGO the credentials at VCAP_SERVICES got deleted or something like that. I connected the services to the app again on Bluemix and the credentials got recreated